# LDAP User cannot logout, reboot or shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I am considering to deploy ElementaryOS as lightweight terminals in an Active Directory environment. I have LDAP configured on ElementaryOS and, as long as the user account exists locally, the user can log on just fine. The homedir is created and GUI is set up.

Creating the user as follows:

```
useradd MyUser
usermod -aD MyUser adm cdrom dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

With the exception of sudo, these are all of the groups that the default user has as well.

When trying to log out, reboot or shut down the machine, none work.

Behavior:
- Log Out: The logout menu shows, the red button can be pressed, but nothing happens. The menu remains open until cancel is pressed.
- Restart: The shutdown menu appears, pressing the restart button closes the menu without doing anything.
- Shutdown: The shutdown menu appears, pressing the shutdown button does nothing.

It is happening on multiple different physical machine models, as well as on Virtualbox VM's.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you try https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25288/unable-to-logout-with-network-account-ldap ?