# Unable to logout with network account (LDAP)

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel, networking

running `elementary OS 5.1.6 Hera` the logout doesn't work anymore after replacing the local account login by LDAP account login.

`journalctl` reports

```
Jul 17 15:35:01 eos wingpanel[4311]: EndSessionDialog.vala:184: Unable to logout:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.NoUserForPID: Caller does not belong to any logged in user or lingering user
```

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/60496 mentioned a problem with `light-locker` but I didn't notice a problem with `light-locker` on the system.

Logout with local accounts work fine.

Any ideas?

Edit:

For some reason the problem is solved after installing Debug-Symbols:

```
apt install libnss-ldapd-dbgsym
```

Comment: Just noticed that screen locking reports a `wingpanel` error in `journalctl` as well:


Jul 21 16:56:13 eos wingpanel[1525]: Indicator.vala:163: Unable to lock: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver was not provided by any .service files

Answer (score 0):

Report the issue on Elementary OS github here: https://github.com/elementary/os/issues

Comment: Thy, done here: https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/386